# Java: Cannot find a method's symbol even though that method is declared later in the class. The remaining code is looking for a class.

Tags: java, methods, boolean, character, symbols

This is an assignment that we use strings in Java to analyze a phone number.
The error I am having is anything below tester=invalidCharacters(c); does not compile because every line past tester=invalidCharacters(c); is looking for a symbol or the class. In get invalidResults, all I am trying to do is evaluate a given string for non-alphabetical characters such as *,(,^,&,%,@,#,), and so on.

**What to answer:**
Why is it producing an error, what will work, and is there an easier method WITHOUT using regex.

Here is the link to the assignment:
http://cis.csuohio.edu/~hwang/teaching/cis260/assignments/assignment9.html

```
public class PhoneNumber {
            private int areacode;
            private int number;
            private int ext;

            /////Constructors/////
            //Third Constructor (given one string arg) "xxx-xxxxxxx" where first three are numbers and the remaining (7) are numbers or letters
            public PhoneNumber(String newNumber){
                    //Note: Set default ext to 0
                    ext=0;

                    ////Declare Temporary Storage and other variables////
                    //for the first three numbers
                    String areaCodeString;
                    //for the remaining seven characters
                    String newNumberString;
                    //For use in testing the second half of the string
                    boolean containsLetters;
                    boolean containsInvalid;

                    /////Separate the two parts of string/////
                    //Get the area code part of the string
                    areaCodeString=newNumber.substring(0,2);
                    //Convert the string and set it to the area code
                    areacode=Integer.parseInt(areaCodeString);

                    //Skip the "-" and Get the remaining part of the string
                    newNumberString=newNumber.substring(4);

                    //Create an array of characters from newNumberString to reuse in later methods for
                    int length=newNumberString.length();
                    char [] myCharacters= new char [length];
                    int i;
                    for (i=0;i<length;i++){
                        myCharacters [i]=newNumberString.charAt(i);
                    }

                    //Test if newNumberString contains letters & converting them into numbers
                    String reNewNumber="";
                    //Test for invalid characters
                    containsInvalid=getInvalidResults(newNumberString,length);
                    if (containsInvalid==false){
                        containsLetters=getCharResults(newNumberString,length);
                        if (containsLetters==true){
                            for (i=0;i<length;i++){
                            myCharacters [i]=(char)convertLetNum((myCharacters [i]));
                            reNewNumber=reNewNumber+myCharacters[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (containsInvalid==false){
                    number=Integer.parseInt(reNewNumber);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Error!"+"\t"+newNumber+" contains illegal characters. This number will be ignored and skipped.");
                    }
            }

            //////Primary Methods/Behaviors///////
            //Compare this phone number with the one passed by the caller
            public boolean equals(PhoneNumber pn){
                boolean equal;
                String concat=(areacode+"-"+number);
                String pN=pn.toString();
                if (concat==pN){
                    equal=true;
                }
                else{
                    equal=false;
                }
                return equal;
            }
            //Convert the stored number to a certain string depending on extension
            public String toString(){
                String returned;
                if(ext==0){
                    returned=(areacode+"-"+number);
                }
                else{
                    returned=(areacode+"-"+number+" ext "+ext);
                }
                return returned;
            }

            //////Secondary Methods///////
            //Method for testing if the second part of the string contains any letters
            public static boolean getCharResults(String newNumString,int getLength){
                //Recreate a character array
                int i;
                char [] myCharacters= new char [getLength];
                for (i=0;i<getLength;i++){
                    myCharacters [i]=newNumString.charAt(i);
                }
                boolean doesContainLetter=false;
                int j;
                for (j=0;j<getLength;j++){
                if ((Character.isDigit(myCharacters[j])==true)){
                    doesContainLetter=false;
                }
                else{
                    doesContainLetter=true;
                    return doesContainLetter;
                }
                }
                return doesContainLetter;
            }
            //Method for testing if the second part of the string contains any letters
            public static boolean getInvalidResults(String newNumString,int getLength){
                boolean doesContainInvalid=false;
                int i;
                char c;
                boolean tester;
                char [] invalidCharacters= new char [getLength];
                for (i=0;i<getLength;i++){
                    invalidCharacters [i]=newNumString.charAt(i);
                    c=invalidCharacters [i];
                    tester=invalidCharacters(c);
                    if(tester==true)){
                        doesContainInvalid=false;
                    }
                    else{
                        doesContainInvalid=true;
                        return doesContainInvalid;
                    }
                }
                    return doesContainInvalid;
            }

            //Method for evaluating string for invalid characters
            public boolean invalidCharacters(char letter){
                boolean returnNum=false;
                    switch (letter){
                        case 'A': return returnNum;
                        case 'B': return returnNum;
                        case 'C': return returnNum;
                        case 'D': return returnNum;
                        case 'E': return returnNum;
                        case 'F': return returnNum;
                        case 'G': return returnNum;
                        case 'H': return returnNum;
                        case 'I': return returnNum;
                        case 'J': return returnNum;
                        case 'K': return returnNum;
                        case 'L': return returnNum;
                        case 'M': return returnNum;
                        case 'N': return returnNum;
                        case 'O': return returnNum;
                        case 'P': return returnNum;
                        case 'Q': return returnNum;
                        case 'R': return returnNum;
                        case 'S': return returnNum;
                        case 'T': return returnNum;
                        case 'U': return returnNum;
                        case 'V': return returnNum;
                        case 'W': return returnNum;
                        case 'X': return returnNum;
                        case 'Y': return returnNum;
                        case 'Z': return returnNum;
                        default: return true;
                    }

            }
            //Method for converting letters to numbers
            public int convertLetNum(char letter){
                int returnNum;
                    switch (letter){
                        case 'A': returnNum=2;return returnNum;
                        case 'B': returnNum=2;return returnNum;
                        case 'C': returnNum=2;return returnNum;
                        case 'D': returnNum=3;return returnNum;
                        case 'E': returnNum=3;return returnNum;
                        case 'F': returnNum=3;return returnNum;
                        case 'G': returnNum=4;return returnNum;
                        case 'H': returnNum=4;return returnNum;
                        case 'I': returnNum=4;return returnNum;
                        case 'J': returnNum=5;return returnNum;
                        case 'K': returnNum=5;return returnNum;
                        case 'L': returnNum=5;return returnNum;
                        case 'M': returnNum=6;return returnNum;
                        case 'N': returnNum=6;return returnNum;
                        case 'O': returnNum=6;return returnNum;
                        case 'P': returnNum=7;return returnNum;
                        case 'Q': returnNum=7;return returnNum;
                        case 'R': returnNum=7;return returnNum;
                        case 'S': returnNum=7;return returnNum;
                        case 'T': returnNum=8;return returnNum;
                        case 'U': returnNum=8;return returnNum;
                        case 'V': returnNum=8;return returnNum;
                        case 'W': returnNum=9;return returnNum;
                        case 'X': returnNum=9;return returnNum;
                        case 'Y': returnNum=9;return returnNum;
                        case 'Z': returnNum=9;return returnNum;
                        default: return 0;
                    }

        }
    }
```

Note: Please Do not use this program to cheat in your own class. To ensure of this, I will take this question down if it has not been answered by the end of 2013, if I no longer need an explanation for it, or if the term for the class has ended.

Comment: You don't need all the `returnNum` statements.  Just return the number directly.  Additionally, create a `Map<Character, Integer>` as a `final static` variable, and use `Map.get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this process was a lot easier than it seemed. The key was to use the constructor, the getCharResults() method, and the switch statement to my advantage.

In the case of the constructor, anything below the declaration of reNewNumber should be the following:

```
int i;
containsLetters=getCharResults(newNumberString,length);
if (containsLetters==true){
    for (i=0;i<length;i++){
        //Resets area code to 0 if a character is invalid (aka !@#$%^&* and so on)
        if((Character.isLetterOrDigit(myCharacters [i]))==false){
            areacode=0;
        }
        //Converts every character to a number (stored as a character)
        myCharacters [i]=convertLetNum((myCharacters [i]));
        //Recreates the string in all-number format
        reNewNumber=reNewNumber+myCharacters[i];
            }
    }
    number=Integer.parseInt(reNewNumber);
}
```

and the getCharResults() method should be expanded to:

```
public static boolean getCharResults(String newNumString,int getLength){
        //Recreate a character array
        char [] myCharacters=newNumString.toCharArray();
        boolean doesContainLetter=false;
        int j;
        for (j=0;j<getLength;j++){
            //Tests if character is a digit
            if ((Character.isDigit(myCharacters[j])==true)){
                doesContainLetter=false;
            }
            //Tests if character is an illegal character and prints out the required error message
            else if((Character.isLetterOrDigit(myCharacters[j])==false)){
                System.out.println("Error!"+"\t"+newNumString+" contains illegal characters. Any invalid character will be set to zero.");
                doesContainLetter=true;
                return doesContainLetter;
            }
            //Test if the character is a letter
            else{
                doesContainLetter=true;
                return doesContainLetter;
            }
        }
        return doesContainLetter;
}
```

and finally the convertLetNum() method should be:

```
public char convertLetNum(char letter){
        char returnNum;
```

where returnNum returns a number as a ***char type***.

Additionally, we add cases to test and return characters that are already numbers, like the following:

```
                case '0': returnNum='0';return returnNum;
                case '1': returnNum='1';return returnNum;
                case '2': returnNum='2';return returnNum;
                case '3': returnNum='3';return returnNum;
                case '4': returnNum='4';return returnNum;
                case '5': returnNum='5';return returnNum;
                case '6': returnNum='6';return returnNum;
                case '7': returnNum='7';return returnNum;
                case '8': returnNum='8';return returnNum;
                case '9': returnNum='9';return returnNum;
```

Do note that returnNum is not needed, but the '#' is.

Any additional code is redundant and unnecessary. If set up right in the constructor, the resulting code is flawless.

Answer (score 1):

`getInvalidResults` is a static method trying to call the non-static `invalidCharacters` method. That is not allowed since non-static methods require an instance of the class. `invalidCharacters` should be static in this case.

Comment: invalidCharacters is also a char[] in that method.